# New PayPal API - How to refund an "order"?

Tags: php, paypal

Paypal (Github): payments/OrderCreateForCapture.html

Based on this I want to do a refund. Somehow I only find refunds for sales in the API documentation. From this Order Capture I **can not** get a SALE ID, so how can I refund it with the new PHP API? There is not really a solution.

This is the way I get the payment:
http://codepaste.net/c5cpos

This is how I take it in:
http://codepaste.net/3yscci

But now I also want to be able to refund it... Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

An payment with the Payment action set to 'Order' is not made yet. The transaction is triggered only when you capture the order with a specific API call.

So it's obvious you cannot refund an order because not payment was done.

You can read more about Order, Authorization and Capture here: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/authcapture/